# RAISE NOTICE not appearing on screen

Tags: postgresql

I have the following trigger that checks if space used > quota and increments the quota by 5. The quota is successfully incremented but the RAISE NOTICE does not appear on the screen.

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION checkspaceused() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $cssubscription$
 DECLARE
 new_spaceused INTEGER; 
 new_id INTEGER; 
 new_quota INTEGER ;
 BEGIN
    IF(TG_OP='UPDATE') THEN
        IF NEW.spaceused > NEW.quota THEN
        RAISE NOTICE 'Limit breached';
        UPDATE subscription SET quota = NEW.spaceused + 5 where u_id = NEW.u_id; 
        END IF ; 

    END IF;

RETURN NEW; 
END;
$cssubscription$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
CREATE TRIGGER checkspaceused AFTER UPDATE ON subscription FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE checkspaceused();
```

Help please.

Comment: How are you running the function?  In Java, for example, you would need to invoke the `getWarnings()` method to see this.  PostgreSQL command-line executables should be showing the notice as long as (as already mentioned in another answer) the `client_min_messages` setting allows it.

Answer (score 10):

Check the value for [`client_min_messages`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-CLIENT-MIN-MESSAGES) in your session - it should be `NOTICE` or later to see notices.

Comment: how does one go about checking this value?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/config-setting.html#CONFIG-SETTING-SQL-COMMAND-INTERACTION

Comment: `Show client_min_messages`

Answer (score 5):

Do this, before you execute the function..

```
SET client_min_messages TO NOTICE;
```

... and then check the Messages tab if using pgAdmin